# JOOQ : Get fiscal quarter with custom month range

Tags: jooq

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/datetime-functions/quarter-function/

This works fine for a normal quarter. what if I want to make it work for a fiscal quarter with a custom month?

---

FISCAL QUARTER MEANS.. instead of January as the starting month of the first quarter it can be any month.

If I consider August as the first month of my fiscal year.

My fiscal quarter look likes these :

```
Aug-Sep-Oct'2021 => 1st fiscal quarter '2021
Nov-Dec-Jan'2022 => 2nd fiscal quarter '2021
Feb-March-April'2022 => 3rd fiscal quarter '2021
May-June-July'2022 => 4th fiscal quarter '2021
```

Comment: What does "fiscal quarter" mean, formally?

Comment: @LukasEder have updated the question description

Answer (score 1):

If your fiscal quarters are strictly month based, why not do some arithmetic on the [`DSL.month(date)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#month(org.jooq.Field)), such as:

```java
trunc(month(DATE_COLUMN).add(4).div(3)).mod(4).add(1)
```

An example in PostgreSQL:

```sql
select d, trunc((extract(month from d) + 4) / 3) % 4 + 1
from (
  select (date '2000-01-01' + i * interval '1 month')::date
  from generate_series(0, 11) as t(i)
) t(d)
```

Resulting in

```
|d         |?column?|
|----------|--------|
|2000-01-01|2       |
|2000-02-01|3       |
|2000-03-01|3       |
|2000-04-01|3       |
|2000-05-01|4       |
|2000-06-01|4       |
|2000-07-01|4       |
|2000-08-01|1       |
|2000-09-01|1       |
|2000-10-01|1       |
|2000-11-01|2       |
|2000-12-01|2       |
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c3bc98abc0efa12a94deec489155369c). Now, depending on whatever the first month of your fiscal year is, adapt the formula accordingly, by toggling the `add(4)` value.

Comment: Kind of what I want. but exactly what I want is my 2nd Fiscal quarter to be consisting of Nov-2000, Dec-2000 and Jan-2001.....

Comment: @moovon: you can probably take it from here? Adding the patched year to the quarter will work the same way